# Set Notification for AWS Data Lifecycle Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Need assistance to setup Notification after creation/deletion of EBS volume Snapshots,

once DLM Policy is implemented at schedule time to create and auto delete snapshot after specific retention time frame, how we can point SNS service to DLM to send email notification for any changes in AWS Life cycle Manager.

Answer (score 3):

There are two out-of-the-box DLM CloudWatch metrics available (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html#dlm-monitor-lifecycle) which could be used to trigger a Lambda to send an email via SES (search for 'boto3 email' for info). If you need another event, you could set up a custom CW metric by matching a specific API call using filters.

Comment: thank you. use alarm and DLM is never thinking of